# I need to build an sql Query using select retrieving object

Tags: php, mysql

i am having trouble in writing SQL query

I have a database mysql CRICKET:

```
id  cricketer run cricketer2 run2 cricketer3 run3
9    dhoni    100   ashwin    50    raina     25
10    ABD     100   gayle     99    virat     15
```

Using the above database i have to take cricketers and add
n=3;

```
$sql = "select (cricketer+cricketer2+cricketer3) as crick, 
               (run+run2+run3/n) as run 
        from CRICKET 
        WHERE id ='9' "
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

I need the data look like this after using select query

```
crick  run
dhoni  58
ashwin 58
raina  58*
```

can anyone adjust the query my above query is not working

Comment: can you tell me, run showing in the field is avg. value ? and You may need to display like this ?  
crick  run
dhoni  58
ashiwn 58
raina  58
ABD    71.33
gayle  71.33
virat  71.33

Am I right ?

Comment: @sleepy , you should explain what you are trying to achieve. Not just the final outcome

Comment: oh sorry i am doing one project and i cant reveal the secret so i will post only the snippet @srinath

Comment: @miqdad all the run must add i.e run+run2+run3 and divide by 3 dynamically it must get the avg value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT
            *
        FROM
            CRICKET
        WHERE
            id = 9
    ";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($resul,MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $avg_run = ($row['run'] + $row['run2'] + $row['run3'])/3
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Crick</td>
        <td>Run</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['cricketer']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $avg_run; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['cricketer2']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $avg_run; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['cricketer3']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $avg_run; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `cricheter`, `cricketer2`, `cricketer3`, 
         ROUND ( (`run` + `run2` + `run3`)/3 ) AS result
                FROM `run` WHERE `id` = 9;
```

This will return:

```
 cricheter   cricketer2   cricketer3   result
   dhoni       ashwin       raina        58
```

If that's what you want...

P.S. The structure of the table can and should probably be improved.